# What is the maximum possible input size for a Resnet model? (v2, 101)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, resnet

When i look up resnet models on tfhub.dev it usually says something like "The expected size of the input images is height x width = 224 x 224 pixels by default, but **other input sizes are possible (within limits)**."

What are those limits? I can't find more information about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using include_top=True (3,224,224) or (224,224,3) input shape is necessary. If you give up on dense layers and give include_top=False, then you can change your input_shape; in this case, the documentation says:
"It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 32. E.g. (200, 200, 3) would be one valid value."
in https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/